# Javascript getJSON to PHP file in IIS using jsonp with variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iis

I am hosting an HTML5, JavaScript, and CSS3 https application on Windows IIS (Internet Information Services).  How the root directory looks is this:

`index.html`, `src/index.js`, `src/send_payment.php`

I am trying to return a simple string at the moment from the php file using getJSON with jsonp (for security).  Here is non-working code:

**index.js**

```
var json_obj = {
    "data_value": 5489798123489725,
    "payment_amount": 10.50,
}
var json_str = JSON.stringify(json_obj);
$.getJSON("https://localhost:443/src/send_payment.php?callback=?", "json_str=" + json_str, function (data) {
    try {
        console.log("SUCCESS >> " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("ERROR >> " + e.toString());
    }
});
```

**send_payment.php**

```
<?php
    try {
        // 1. get data
        $json_str = $_GET["json_str"];

        // 2. parse the json string
        $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);

        // 3. get the parameters
        $data_value = $json_obj->{"data_value"};
        $payment_amount = $json_obj->{"payment_amount"};

    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        trigger_error("ERROR >> exception = " + $e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    return "test successful";
?>
```

I'm not sure if the code is right or missing anything, but the issue is that I get 404 (Page not found) from getJSON.  Is the URL wrong?  I am accessing IIS locally, thus the `localhost` in the URL.  I get error 405 (Method not allowed) when using AJAX POST instead with the same URL.  Thank you.

Comment: I think the POST is getting blocked by IIS, thus the 405.  So I should stick with GET instead, which should not be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go for $.ajax and POST method like below:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'src/send_payment.php',
        async: false,
        data: {'data_value': 5489798123489725,'payment_amount': 10.5 },
        success: function (response) {
            //do whatever you want here            }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am still getting 404.

Comment: It turns out that I needed to install php for IIS, and now it works.